# I got a way of removing nulls from a String[], how can i make a method for that function and later call on it? Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am new to java and just started working with String arrays. I have a function for removing all nulls and since I use it multiple times in my code I thought that a method would be appropriate. So that when I have an array with Nulls, I can call on that particular method and remove all of them.

Right now the function is:

```
    int countNull = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] == null) {
            countNull++;
        }
    }

    String[] noNull = new String[myArray.length - countNull];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] != null)
            noNull[j] = myArray[i];
            j++;
    }
```

How do I make that in to a method that I can call on and simple say something along the lines of `myArray = noNull`?

Comment: [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) would be better places to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method:

```
public static String[] removeNulls(String[] array) {
    int countNull = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == null) {
            countNull++;
        }
    }

    String[] noNull = new String[array.length - countNull];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] != null)
            noNull[j] = myArray[i];
            j++;
    }
    return noNull;
}
```

I would put this method into a class called `ArrayUtils`:

```
final class ArrayUtils {
    private ArrayUtils() {}

    // put the method here...
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
someArray = ArrayUtils.removeNulls(someArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap all your code above into a static method taking myArray as argument an return noNull.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the `j++` bit out. I misread the OP's code, but our edits clashed with each other.